# Do you need to wear a magic item in order to to use it

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items

If you have a bracelet of friends, do you need to wear it or can you take it out of your bag and use it

Comment: [Related.](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/70608/8610)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The text describing a magic item states this:

> **Bracelet of Friends**
>   This silver charm bracelet has four charms upon it when created. The
>   owner may designate one person known to him to be keyed to one charm.
>   (This designation takes a standard action, but once done it lasts
>   forever or until changed.) When a charm is grasped and the name of the
>   keyed individual is spoken, that person is called to the spot (a
>   standard action) along with his or her gear, as long as the owner and
>   the called person are on the same plane. The keyed individual knows
>   who is calling, and the bracelet of friends only functions on willing
>   travelers. Once a charm is activated, it disappears. Charms separated
>   from the bracelet are worthless. A bracelet found with fewer than four
>   charms is worth 25% less for each missing charm.

While there is nothing in the text of this particular magic item that dictates that it must be worn, the rules about magic items on the body dictates otherwise:

> Many magic items need to be donned by a character who wants to employ them or benefit from their abilities. It’s possible for a creature with a humanoid-shaped body to wear as many as twelve magic items at the same time. However, each of those items must be worn on (or over) a particular part of the body. [...]
>   *Some items can be worn or carried without taking up space on a character’s body. **The description of an item indicates when an item
>   has this property.***

So yeah, this magic item must be worn to be used - through nothing states that you've got to wear it for any indicated time (unlike the *Ring of Sustenance*, for example, that you must wear for 24 hours to gain any benefits from it), so you can wear anything else on this item slot (like, Bracers of Armor) and then just take them off and put Bracelet of Friends on if you need to call the designated target. Sure, it's not as combat-sufficient, but it's still an option.

Comment: No,  you can only wear 2 rings at a time. The actual slots are: Head (hat), Face (lenses), Throat (amulet), Back (cape), Torso (vest), Body (robe), Wrists (bracers), Hands (gloves), Rings (one on each hand), Belt, Legs (boots)

Comment: I've heard some controversy about wearing multiple rings or necklaces. It's clear that only two rings can be *active* at a time, but is it crystal clear that only two can be worn? I do not remember reading any conclusive evidence.

Comment: Well, according to the rules, the character CAN carry more than that, but those extra items won't work at all. I imagine that after a certain point, those extra worn amulets or rings start getting in the way of determining which should work after a switch (which can get REALLY nasty in combat) http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicItemBasics.htm#magicItemsOnTheBody